# How to change table row background color from KO's binding method?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm using KO.js to bind a table body with many rows. The first column has some buttons, if user clicks on a button of a row, I want that row be highlighted. But I don't know how to reference to the table row from Ko's binding method.

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTtFu/) I'm talking about.

and some code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: frameworks">
        <td>
            <button class=btn data-bind="click: $parent.doStuff">A</button>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    </tbody>
</table>


var App = new function () {
        var self = this;
        self.frameworks = ko.observableArray();
        self.doStuff = function () {
            //how to change table row color?
        };
    };

App.frameworks.push('bootstrap');
App.frameworks.push('knockout.js');
ko.applyBindings(App);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close. I have updated your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yTtFu/1/) with the solution.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: frameworks">
        <tr data-bind="css: {'selected':$root.selectedItem() == $data}">
            <td>
                <button class=btn data-bind="click: $root.doStuff">A</button>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.selected
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Javascript

```
    var App = new function () {
        var self = this;
        self.frameworks = ko.observableArray();
        self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
        self.doStuff = function (item) {
            self.selectedItem(item);
            //do other things here for the button click
        };
    };

    App.frameworks.push('bootstrap');
    App.frameworks.push('knockout.js');
    ko.applyBindings(App);
```

Comment: Here's a solution that does not require the button: http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/yTtFu/38/.  Just move the click event to the row.